# Show default component in Outlet

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I show a default component in an `Outlet`? I have the following in `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<App/>}>
                  <Route path="page1" element={<Page1/>}/>
                  <Route path='page2' element={<Page2/>}/>
              </Route>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here's `App.js`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link> {' '}
        <Link to='/page1'>Page 1</Link> {' '}
        <Link to='/page2'>Page 2</Link>

        <main>
            <Outlet/>
        </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click on either the Page 1 or Page 2 link, components `Page1` or `Page` are displayed in the `Outlet`. When at the root route ("/"), I want to display a default component, like `<p>Home</p>` in the `Outlet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Outlet` components is used to render the child route contents only, it is a kind of placeholder. Since there is no content other than the Outlet, nothing will be rendered in the `/` route other than the links.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);

function App() {
   return (
     <div className="App">

       <nav>
         <Link to='/'>Home</Link> {' '}
         <Link to='/page1'>Page 1</Link> {' '}
         <Link to='/page2'>Page 2</Link>
       </nav>

        <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
           <Route path="page1" element={<Page1/>}/>
           <Route path='page2' element={<Page2/>}/>
        </Routes>
    </div>
    );
   }
```

Comment: I kind of get what you're saying, but with the above the ```<p>``` is displayed every time.

Comment: Yes exactly, because /page1 and /page2 is the nested routes of ```/```. That means, the contents available in the parent route and the corresponding child route will be displayed together. The contents inside the child route will be replaced in the place of ```outlet```.

Comment: If you make the /page1 and /page2 as seperate route instead of nested route, you can get rid of the outlet component

Comment: @user2233706, in case of Fix 2, the Home will not be rendered always.

Comment: I want the navigation links to always be displayed at the top. With Fix 2, the nav link go away after you click page 1/page 2.

Comment: @user2233706, did you try fix 3?

Comment: @user2233706. you mean except Fix 3?

Comment: Yes, sorry meant to have only fix #3. The others don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash points to the root of the route, so any component sitting in it will be displayed as the root directory

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<App/>}>
                  <Route path="/" element={<Page1/>}/>
                  <Route path='page2' element={<Page2/>}/>
              </Route>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this

```
    const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "",
    element: <Home/>
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout/>,
    children:[
    {
      path:'page1',
      element:<Page1/>
    }
    ]
 }
]);
```

Home has Header and the code of homepage,
but Layout has Header  and Outlet element

Comment: I couldn't actually get this to work, but I found the correct way to do it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71480841/2443011