# Check if outlet not exist show some thing else in react router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want in react router 6 to show an placeholder when there is no outlet. Is there any way?

```
<>
   <Grid item xs={12} sm={2} style={{backgroundColor: '#aaa'}}>
      <Button onClick={() => this.props.navigate('next')} variant='contained'>next</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => this.props.navigate(-1)} variant='contained'>back</Button>
   </Grid>
   <Outlet/>
</>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "placeholder" and "when there is no outlet". What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to show list of messages in sidebar and when user click a message show the content in front of it. I think to use /message to show only list of message and /message/12 to show list of messages and also content of message with id 12. now if use only enter /message I need to show some placeholder or any think else in right side until user click a single message

Comment: Can you update your question to include the relevant routing code then? I think I understand your question, but you should still add a relevant code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A very reasonable desire, I'm surprised the official docs don't mention this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can rely on `useOutlet` hook instead. If the result is null render your placeholder. Detail here: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet

```js
// Placeholder is your own implementation
function Page() {
  const outlet = useOutlet()

  return <div>{outlet || <PlaceHolder />}</div>

}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Really hard to find this answer but I'm glad there is a hook. Thanks for sharing, the amount of other hacks I saw were wild haha

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
 <Route
    element = { <div>Please select Chat...</div> }
    path = '*' />
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.